# Are goaltends called on a shooting foul?

Tags: rules, basketball

I'm aware there is a question about blocking a shot off of a foul, but this one is concerned more about blatant goaltending off a fouled shot.

Here's a scenario:

> Player outside the three point line gets fouled on a shot attempt,
>   shot looks good to at least hit the rim but another player on defense jumps
>   and swats the ball away before it even hits the rim.

To my understanding, the ball is dead the moment a referee blows a whistle, except for a shooting foul where the ball can still be counted for an and-one until it bounces back on the court.

If a player goaltends the ball off of a shooting foul, will it be considered a goaltend or will the free throws for the fouled shooter just continue as normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basket would count and the player would get a free throw. According to [NBA.com](https://www.nba.com/analysis/rules_11.html),

> If the goaltending violation is at the opponent's basket, the offended team is awarded two points, if the attempt is from the two point zone and three points if it is from the three point zone. The crediting of the score and subsequent procedure is the same as if the awarded score has resulted from the ball having gone through the basket.

That means the free throw would be awarded and count, as procedures continue as normal. Anytime goaltending is called, the shot counts as if it went in and everything else procedes normally.

Comment: your quote is about the general consequences of goaltending but does not mention the case described in the question.

Comment: @E.Sommer this answers the question because it proves that a free throw would be awarded. In the specific question, it would result in a 4-point play.